# Two fragment from the same class in the same activity not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm test a layout specifically for tablets, and I'm wishing to put two list view, one on the right and one on the left, & in the middle, details will be shown on selection.

The fragment on the right and left will contain a listview. Both will be completely the same without any difference, so when I'm setting the android:name to be similar, only one is showing, only the right, any suggestion?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/photo_list1"
        android:name="com.example.fragments.PhotoListFragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/photo_details_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.fragments.PhotoDetailsFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/photo_list2"
        android:name="com.example.fragments.PhotoListFragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you could use a drawer one the left one on the right like facebook and display details on the screen. You will be reducing space for DetailsFramgent

Comment: what's the minimum api does the navigation drawer supports?

Comment: you can use support library from backward compatibility and still use navigation drawer below api level11

Comment: but can you guess what's the problem above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am giving you a demo for your requirement

**DetailFrag.java** please use support library for lower api if possible

```
public class DetailFrag extends Fragment{
@Override


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override


public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, container, false);
return view;
}


public void setText(String item) {
TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.captain);


view.setText(item);


}


}
```

**ListFrag.java**

```
public class ListFrag extends ListFragment{
@Override


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override


public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
String[] values = new String[] { "Enterprise", "Star Trek", "Next Generation", "Deep Space 9", "Voyager"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
setListAdapter(adapter);


}


@Override


public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);


DetailFrag frag = (DetailFrag) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_capt);


if (frag != null && frag.isInLayout()) {
frag.setText(getCapt(item));


}


}


private String getCapt(String ship) {
if (ship.toLowerCase().contains("enterprise")) {
return "Johnathan Archer";
}


if (ship.toLowerCase().contains("star trek")) {
return "James T. Kirk";
}


if (ship.toLowerCase().contains("next generation")) {
return "Jean-Luc Picard";
}


if (ship.toLowerCase().contains("deep space 9")) {
return "Benjamin Sisko";
}


if (ship.toLowerCase().contains("voyager")) {
return "Kathryn Janeway";
}


return "???";
}


}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<fragment
android:id="@+id/frag_series"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.example.fragmentdemo.ListFrag" />
<fragment
android:id="@+id/frag_capt"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.example.fragmentdemo.DetailFrag" />
<fragment
android:id="@+id/frag_series1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.example.fragmentdemo.ListFrag" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**detail_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/captain"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
 android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
 android:text="Johnathan Archer"
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
 android:textSize="30dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

output of the cbove code will be
[image]
hopefully it will help you.

Comment: I have not yet analysed your code, but do you have an idea why my codes isn't working

Comment: @Noor askm i have used your xml it is working fine in my tab having version 2.3.5 I think there should be some problem in your code